# JavaScript timer thread

Tags: javascript, timer, thread-sleep

I have a function checkReg() which checks to see if my device has been registered on a server the first tine it is launched and returns a regStatus variable. The function works fine but it takes a bit of time for the reg to complete and my application cannot proceed without confirming registration is done.

I would like to use a simple thread to check the regStatus once 1 sec and after 5 tries if it hasn't been registered then kill the thread and go back, if it is done before 5 tries then kill the thread and proceed.

```
Thread(run every 1 sec){
    regStatus=checkReg();
    if(regStatus==='done'){

        //do something
        //kill thread
    }else if(regStatus==='inprogress'){

        //do nothing
    }elseif(regStatus==='error'){

        //kill thread
    }
}
```

I am quite new to JS and do not know how to start, time or kill the thread. I have used the setTimeout function but I'm not sure it can do what I want.

Comment: JavaScript is generally single-threaded. Your `checkReg` is making a `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: I believe so, it is a function from a 3rd party SDK I use it must communicate with their server

Comment: @Amanni: Doesn't it provide a callback or something? What does `checkReg` actually do?

Comment: Returns 1, 0 or an error

Comment: @Amanni: Do you have an API reference for that 3rd party SDK? It should tell you if it accepts a callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have threads in general, but you can easily use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) instead:

```
var retry = 0

function checkStatus() {
  var regStatus=checkReg();
  if(regStatus==='done'){
    //...
  }
  if(++retry > 5) {
    clearTimeout(id);
  }
}

var id = setInterval(checkStatus, 1000);
```

Comment: If `regStatus` is making a synchronous request, it's still going to block. Using a `setTimeout` won't prevent that. It just delays its execution for a second.

Comment: @user1689607: you are right, I assumed `checkReg()` is not that slow to affect `setTimeout()` frequency. If it is, OP will have bigger problems with UI responsiveness. Of course he can use `setTimeout()` and calculate delay every time (1 second minus `checkReg()` run time).

Comment: I does block but for less than 5 seconds except there is an error then it's just five seconds. I'll use this until I can find a solution that doesn't block.

Comment: @Amanni your `checkReg()` function blocks for 5 seconds and you want to run it every second? Also is the browser freezing for these 5 seconds?